# Android, out of memory in custom View

Tags: android, image, memory, memory-management

I am stress testing an app that consists of a bunch of custom views (3 in fact) that are held in a frameLayout.

Only two are held at a time though. I have view 1, add view two, animate out 1 and animate in 2, then remove 1, and vice versa if I go bacward throug hthe views.

Each view then loads a large amount of image data when it is created using the following method:

```
mBmp[background] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open("view1_background.png"));
```

Below is an example of my View switching code, this switching forward, to the nextView.

```
currView.startAnimation(AnimClass.outToLeftAnimation(null));
    intView++;
    nextView = ViewFactory.getInstance(this, intView, viewInitializer);
    mainLayout.addView(nextView, 0);
    nextView.startAnimation(AnimClass.inFromRightAnimation(this));
    mainLayout.removeViewInLayout(currView);
    currView = nextView;
    nextView = null;
```

viewInitializer calls a Custom view depending on the intView and instantiates it which then loads the images using the above method.

The problem is that if I switch the views fast enough I can cause it to stop keeping up (even though i'm disabling the buttons until the slide out animation is finished) and after a few switches I will lose most of the images in a view and just end up with one or two of the smallest images still there. It does not show any errors when this happens except the following messages (one per image in that view):

```
01-27 13:52:00.730: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 139264
01-27 13:52:01.011: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 425984
01-27 13:52:01.011: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 1187840
01-27 13:52:01.011: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 139264
01-27 13:52:01.093: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 139264
01-27 13:52:01.128: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 425984
01-27 13:52:01.144: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 1187840
01-27 13:52:01.179: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 139264
01-27 13:52:01.245: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 425984
01-27 13:52:01.261: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 139264
01-27 13:52:01.277: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 1187840
01-27 13:52:01.343: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 139264
01-27 13:52:01.363: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 425984
01-27 13:52:01.409: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 1187840
01-27 13:52:01.429: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 139264
01-27 13:52:01.511: DEBUG/skia(23064): ------- imageref_ashmem create failed <(null)> 139264
```

If I switch views, it does the same on every view. It seems to me that my view switching code isn't deallocating the views when they or removed, or the images (bitmaps) arent being deallocated once the view is removed.

If I then use an intent to return to my main activity I get the following:

```
Surface  E  Surface (identity=4810) requestBuffer(0, 00000033) returneda buffer with a null handle
Surface  E  getBufferLocked(0, 00000033) failed (Out of memory)
Surface  E  dequeueBuffer failed (Out of memory)
ViewRoot  E  OutOfResourcesException locking surface
ViewRoot  E  android.view.Surface$OutOfResourcesException
ViewRoot  E     at android.view.Surface.lockCanvasNative(Native Method)
ViewRoot  E     at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:314)
ViewRoot  E     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1363)
ViewRoot  E     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1172)
ViewRoot  E     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1749)
ViewRoot  E     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
ViewRoot  E     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
ViewRoot  E     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
ViewRoot  E     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
ViewRoot  E     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
ViewRoot  E     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
ViewRoot  E     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
ViewRoot  E     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone suggest where I might have gone wrong?

**EDIT: Didn't find the exact cause, but I solved the problem by performing a garbage collect between switching views.**

Comment: Hamid , Did you tried using SoftReference?

Comment: No, I didnt try because from my understanding this would allow the system to remove my images from memory even while I am using them? Is this a correct understanding? It's not acceptable for it to remove images while my view is still in focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you thought about using bitmap options to import smaller images that take up less image data? If you have high res images (eg. camera photos) it is never necessary to show users the full image resolution.

try doing this before you import the bitmap

```
Options options = new Options();            
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

BitmapFactory.decodeFile(context.getAssets().open("view1_background.png"), options);

options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), 
            "height: " + options.outHeight +
            "\nwidth: " + options.outWidth +
            "\nmimetype: " + options.outMimeType +
            "\nsample size: " + options.inSampleSize);

options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

mBmp[background] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open("view1_background.png"));
```

where in sample size is determined by the following:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize( Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
{
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    while (height / inSampleSize > reqHeight || width / inSampleSize > reqWidth) 
    {
        if (height > width)
        {
            inSampleSize = height / reqHeight;
            if (((double)height % (double)reqHeight) != 0) 
            {
                inSampleSize++;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            inSampleSize = width / reqWidth;
            if (((double)width % (double)reqWidth) != 0) 
            {
                inSampleSize++;
            }
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the images were for an animated book, and were pixel perfect for the screen they were displayed on. Scaling the images was an impossibility. I'm not longer working on the project, however, so hopefully I can accept one of these answers that may be useful to others.

Comment: thanks for accepting and sorry I wasn't able to help with your exact case

Comment: No problem. Thanks for giving it a shot, even so long after the original question. No doubt your answer will come in useful to others now.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer some sort of "cleaning up" when working with a lot of images... Have you tried to deinitialize (recycle bitmaps) the images you load before you remove the view from the layout?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this, unfortunately I get a null pointer because of attempting to use the bitmaps that have just been recycled. I don't really understand why it would still want to use these when it has already been animated out of view (off-screen)and then removed from the layout. (I recycled AFTER removing from layout, kills my app with null pointer.

Comment: You should debug that behavior and take a look on the object id you use when you switch. maybe you are not creating a new one but reusing the old one? Thats what happened to me not long ago...

Comment: Well, I have 3 view objects (prev, current and next), when I switch back or forward I instantiate the new view into the prev or next respectively, switch current with prev or next, then remove current and assign prev or next to current.

Comment: I know that, but have you proved that by logging the id of the objects you create and use? Why do you create a new view anyway? why not just "clean" the prev one and reuse the instance when you need it again?

Comment: Added logging to check the IDs, it is definitely putting the right views in the right places. As for not reusing, each view is unique, each with it's own class. There are many, and the number is arbitrary.

Comment: Than you can only look at the stack trace to find out the call hierarchy. With that you might find a answer to "why it would still want to use these"